# Symfony2 security and X-WSSE http header

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

I try to follow the cookbook to create my own Authentication Provider.

Here is the wsse listener :

```
$request = $event->getRequest();

$wsseRegex = '/UsernameToken Username="([^"]+)", PasswordDigest="([^"]+)", Nonce="([^"]+)", Created="([^"]+)"/';
if (!$request->headers->has('x-wsse') || 1 !== preg_match($wsseRegex, $request->headers->get('x-wsse'), $matches)) {
    return;
}

$token = new WsseUserToken();...
```

As you can see to create the wsse token, the http request needs to have the x-wsse header.

In my case it is never present.

QUESTION : When exactly should this header be sent and how ?

I thought that, mybe, it would be after I entered the username and the password using the security.yml :

```
wsse_secured:
        pattern:    ^/
        wsse: true
```

because of the wsse : true...

The result of this problem is that the token used is not the one I defined but the default one.

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you understood the way `WSSE` works. Your application does **not** send the headers - the client has to include them in his request.

`WSSE` authentication is mostly used by API's (i.e. SOAP).

It is somewhat similar to Basic HTTP authentication but provides a little better security.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/17/dive.html)**.

In order to authenticate your client (browser,application,etc) has to provide the WSSE authentication headers in the HTTP request.

The authentication headers can be generated with the [JavaScript WSSE Header Generator](http://www.teria.com/~koseki/tools/wssegen/)

You can simulate a request with a WSSE header from a browser plugin like:

- [Rest Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en) (Chrome)
- [Rest Client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) (Firefox)
- [Modheader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj) (Chrome)
- [ModifyHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) (Firefox)